# dynamically assign class in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Hi I have the following haml:

```
.btn-group-wrap{style:'text-align:center;'}
  .btn-group{style: 'display: inline-block; text-align:center; width:inherit;'}
    =link_to "All Users", users_path, class: 'btn active'
    =link_to "Search", '#', class:'btn'
```

I want to be able to toggle back and forth between `active` class for each of the links. ie if `params[:controller] == "users"` then I want that to be `active`. If `params[:controller] =="search"` then it will make the users class just `'btn'` and Search `'btn active'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
.btn-group-wrap{style:'text-align:center;'}
  .btn-group{style: 'display: inline-block; text-align:center; width:inherit;'}
    =link_to "All Users", users_path, class: button_class
    =link_to "Search", '#', class:'btn'
```

Then in `/apps/helpers/application_helper.rb` (or whichever helper seems most appropriate):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def button_class
    if params[:controller] == "users" 
      'active'
    elsif params[:controller] =="search"
      'btn active'
    else
      # default value
      'btn'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi make it helper method and in helper method renders class name as per your requirement.
Refer http://iparamtech.blogspot.in/2012/04/dynamic-sidebar-in-rails-layout.html